# Calling a C++ app from PHP - output shows "Array"

Tags: php, c++, ubuntu, web

I was wondering if anyone could help me, I want to call a small application that simply returns the input that it has been given - it is just a simple test to see if I can control a C++ app from php using Ubuntu. however, all I get is "Array" when I should get "Hello".

Am I doing this correctly?

this is the PHP:

```
<?PHP 
    echo exec('whoami');
echo "---";
    echo exec('pwd');
echo "---";
    echo "Hello World - From PHP";
echo "---";
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "---";
exec('var/www/aws-app-dev Hello', $output);
echo $output;
echo "---";
echo "end";
?>
```

and this is the simple app code (all of it!)

```
#include <iostream> using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

string i; i = argv[1];

cout << "aws-dev-app says | " + i << endl; // prints return 0; }
```

any Idea where this is going wrong?

The output in the browser is:

```
theadmin---/var/www/---Hello World - From PHP---2013-12-02 20:45:15---Array---end
```

however it should be:

```
theadmin---/var/www/---Hello World - From PHP---2013-12-02 20:45:15---Hello---end
```

Answer (score 1):

Always check the documentation first!

From [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/function.exec), we see that the signature for `exec` is

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

Note that `output` (the second parameter) is an array.

> **`output`**
>
> If the **`output`** argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command.

To see what your program is returning, replace:

```
echo $output;
```

with

```
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo exec('var/www/aws-app-dev Hello');
```

This works if your program only returns one line.
You can also do this:

```
exec('var/www/aws-app-dev Hello', $output);
foreach ($output as $line) {
   echo $line, "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: `exec` returns *only the last line of output*.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `echo`s to `print_r` so you can see the full output and then paste that out for us - looks like there are possible line breaks causing PHP to take the output as an array instead of a string.

Comment: `$output` is *always* an array. Check the documentation.